# Uninstalled Amplify CLI but keep getting local IAM credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have a Next.js app connected with Amplify. I logged in to my system using amplify CLI through

```
amplify configure
amplify init
```

I need to remove those credentials, because I want to change the amplify project, so I used

```
amplify remove
amplify uninstall
```

But the project is still connected to the credentials, and I can't logout. What's the problem here?

My project doesn't have any amplify variables hardcoded. I try to use the following command

```
new AdminUserGlobalSignOutCommand({
  UserPoolId: this.clientPoolId,
  Username: username,
})
```

And it is working, when it shouldn't because it's supposed to don't have the credentials.

Comment: which os are you using? what language is your project written in?

Comment: @rleffler I'm using MacOS Ventura 13.1, and the project is built in Next.js using Typescript.

Update: I temporarily fixed the problem by copying and pasting the  "Command line or programmatic access" from AWS Console in my terminal, then running the app and it works.